# What is the better server to use for Apple Push Notification AWS-SNS or Heroku?

Tags: swift, heroku, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am new in swift and quite having a hard time on how I will integrate Notification in my app. I read the apple documentation, tried some tutorial on how I will used Push Notification like [this tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/push-notifications-local-notifications-tutorial/). In this tutorial, I encountered the `Pusher.app` and based on the use of the `Pusher`, you have to click `Push` button to send notification in your device. I am wondering how will I push notification automatically to all the devices with installed `my.app` without clicking the push button like in `Pusher.app`?. Based on my research I have to use web server, is `Heroku` and `AWS-SNS` can be used for Push Notification Server? Which of the two is better and how will I integrate it to my app. Hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: "I have to use web server"  You want one for what?  For sending push notifications?

Comment: I am looking for a web server for push notification but @gmogames told me that technically I don't need a web server to send pushes. He suggested to check OneSignal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you don't need a web server to send pushes, as you can fire pushes from your terminal window if you wanted.
But pushes work basically in the way where once a user accepted to receive notifications, Apple provides you with a device id for that user, and by you having a certificate authenticating your account to send pushes and that device id being registered to your application, you can send messages to it.

Having a web service helps you in saving those device ids and sending messages without having to manage that yourself.

I think the best free option (probably the best) is OneSignal (https://onesignal.com). You can even use their SDK and not have to do much on your side.

But you could build your own service that stores IDs and send pushes using your favorite language, and there are a ton of tutorials out there.

Just make sure you separate the things as you need to setup and configure your app to accept pushes and you need to setup and configure a service that stores the data and fires the notification.

Cheers